# Duda con el algoritmo de la torre de hannoi segun la wikipedia

Tags: algoritmos

Se que es una pregunta algo absurda, pero me gustaría saber del fragmento que sale en la wikipedia, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torres_de_Han%C3%B3i#Mediante_recursividad, que es el 1 en la linea:

```
si origen == {1} entonces
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente indica que la comparación `origen == {1}` comprueba si la pila origen contiene sólo una única ficha, que al ser la 1 sería la más pequeña de todas.

Comment: Vale gracias, pero y en la instrucción 2.1 que significa hanoi({1,...,n-1}, origen, destino, auxiliar). ¿No se supone que tiene 3 parámetros en vez de 4?

Comment: Sí, la función hanoi tiene tres parámetros (origen, auxiliar y destino). Lo que está haciendo en la instrucción 2.1 es llamar recursivamente a la función hanoi pero tomando como pila origen todas las fichas excepto la mayor n. Además en dicha llamada invierte las pilas destino y auxiliar.